# Swift Convert Date to Date with dateFormat

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know the convert
Date to String //
String to Date

with

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"

let date = formatter.date ( from: String )
```

**or**

```
let string = formatter.string ( from: Date )
```

but I want to convert Date to Date with formatting like this 
**"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"** to **"yyyy-MM-dd"** in Date format.

Is there anyway to do this with **one line** ?

Comment: It makes no sense to convert a `Date` to `Date`. Or do you mean to convert `String` to `String` where each string represents a date in two different formats?

Comment: You can write an entire program in one line, if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Answer to your question: **No**.

You can create a date/string extension, that can solve your problem in one-line. Note, `Date` object is a date object. It does not have any format (like string).

May this help you:

```
extension String {


    func convertDateString() -> String? {
        return convert(dateString: self, fromDateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", toDateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
    }


    func convert(dateString: String, fromDateFormat: String, toDateFormat: String) -> String? {

        let fromDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        fromDateFormatter.dateFormat = fromDateFormat

        if let fromDateObject = fromDateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {

            let toDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            toDateFormatter.dateFormat = toDateFormat

            let newDateString = toDateFormatter.string(from: fromDateObject)
            return newDateString
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Use one-line code:

```
let newDateString = "my date string".convertDateString()
```

Comment: no, a date has no components for year, month, date etc... Under the hood is a NSTimeInterval (aka double) representing a point in time. To get month and alike from it, you need to use it with an calendar. refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can always write an extension that does the job for you.

You should extend `Date` with a function that get the format (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`) as an argument, create the special `DateFormatter`, then convert as usual with passages between `String` and `Date`.

Unluckily there is no standard way.